# Delete rows with repeated values in different columns

Tags: r, dataframe

I have two columns in a data frame, and I have been able to delete all duplicate rows with `unique( )` - Works a treat.

But now I want to delete rows were the values are the same, irrespective of which column they are in. like...

```
data1    data2
data3    data2
data2    data1
data2    data3
```

Should be simplified to

```
data1    data2
data3    data2
```

since rows 3 and 4 are the same as 1 and 2.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First sort each row column-wise (using `apply` and `sort`), then use `unique`:

```
dat <- read.table(text="
data1    data2
data3    data2
data2    data1
data2    data3")

unique(t(apply(dat, 1, sort)))
     [,1]    [,2]   
[1,] "data1" "data2"
[2,] "data2" "data3"
```

Comment: +1 @Andrie for clean use of apply.  Interestingly my compiled function takes about 439 micro seconds and the apply takes 515 micro seconds for the small example table with 4 rows.  However for the 4,000 row table it is the other way around at 3.45ms vs 2.92ms.  Overall less difference than I'd expected.

Answer (score 0):

I'd create a new column with the sorted columns you have pasted together, and then unique() that.

```
# create some dummy data
adf <- data.frame(colA=c('data1', 'data3', 'data2', 'data2'),
       colB=c('data2', 'data2', 'data1', 'data3'), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

# function to fix up this data...
# can't see a way of avoiding the loop at the moment, but I'm sure somebody will!
fixit <- function(adf) {
  nc <- vector(mode='character', length=nrow(adf))
  for (i in 1:nrow(adf)) {
    nc[i] <- paste(sort(c(adf[i,1], adf[i,2])), collapse='')
  } 
  adf[!duplicated(nc),]
} 
fixit(adf)
```

Having the loop will be slow on a big data.frame, but it can be sped up by using

```
library(compiler)
faster.fixit <- cmpfun(fixit)
faster.fixit(adf)
```

I know this is slightly off topic, but interestingly when I benchmark this looped function, the byte-compiled version is only about 5% faster

```
# create a bigger test data.frame
N <- 10
adf.bigger <- data.frame(colA=rep(adf$colA, N), colB=rep(adf$colB, N),
               stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

N <- 1000
adf.biggest <- data.frame(colA=rep(adf$colA, N), colB=rep(adf$colB, N),
               stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(fixit(adf), faster.fixit(adf), times=1000L)
microbenchmark(fixit(adf.bigger), faster.fixit(adf.bigger), times=1000L)
microbenchmark(fixit(adf.biggest), faster.fixit(adf.biggest), times=100L)
```

Comment: What is `comfun`? Should that be `cmpfun`?